# 2 lines (multiline) picker for long text

Tags: ios, picker

why can i set the Row hight or multi lines for a picker,
the problem i have long texts for my picker, or gives an line break in picker... xcode 5 ...
i get the values for the picker from an array.
my code for my custom Picker is:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,265,40);
    label.backgroundColor = PickColor;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18 ];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;



    if(component == 0)
    {
        label.text = [_vergehen objectAtIndex:row];
    }
        return label;
}
```

thanks for help

Comment: Try to add 'label.numberOfLines = 2`.

Comment: label.number Of Lines = 2. I've already tried, without success

Comment: What happens if you reduce your font size slightly, or use a larger height for your label?

Comment: @Heisenberg keep the line `label.numberOfLines = 2` and try setting the frame to the label (you're creating the frame but not setting it to the label). You should create your frame taking in consideration the height of your font (`CGRectMake(0,0,265,font.lineHeight*2`)

Comment: when i reduce the font size the compete text is in 1 line, this does not look good... how can I change the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're creating a label, you might try this property of UILabel:

```
// UILabel wraps text across multiple lines
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

If you set `label.numberOfLines = 0`, you should be able to get any number of lines placed within the label.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
  return 50;
}
```

then

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
   UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 310, 50)];
   lblTitle.numberOfLines=2;
   lblTitle.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   lblTitle.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
   lblTitle.text=[selectionList objectAtIndex:row];
   return lblTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UILineBreakModeWordWrap` is deprecated deprecated in iOS 6.0

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;  
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```